# What is causing the npm dependency warning?

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I have a Meteor / React application and it's throwing the following warning:

```
WARNING: npm peer requirements not installed:
 - react@15.3.2 installed, react@0.14.x needed
 - react-dom@15.3.1 installed, react-dom@0.14.x needed
 - react-addons-transition-group@15.3.1 installed, react-addons-transition-group@0.14.x needed
 - react-addons-css-transition-group@15.3.1 installed, react-addons-css-transition-group@0.14.x needed
 - react-addons-linked-state-mixin@15.3.1 installed, react-addons-linked-state-mixin@0.14.x needed
 - react-addons-create-fragment@15.3.1 installed, react-addons-create-fragment@0.14.x needed
 - react-addons-update@15.3.1 installed, react-addons-update@0.14.x needed
 - react-addons-pure-render-mixin@15.3.1 installed, react-addons-pure-render-mixin@0.14.x needed
 - react-addons-test-utils@15.3.1 installed, react-addons-test-utils@0.14.x needed
 - react-addons-perf@15.3.1 installed, react-addons-perf@0.14.x needed
```

The dependencies in my package.json file are as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^0.8.7",
    "browser": "^0.2.6",
    "growl": "^1.9.2",
    "jade": "^1.11.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.2.1",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.3",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-addons-create-fragment": "^15.3.1",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.3.1",
    "react-addons-linked-state-mixin": "^15.3.1",
    "react-addons-perf": "^15.3.1",
    "react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "^15.3.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.3.1",
    "react-addons-transition-group": "^15.3.1",
    "react-addons-update": "^15.3.1",
    "react-data-components": "^1.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-router": "^2.8.1",
    "react-select2-wrapper": "^1.0.2",
    "react-textarea-autosize": "^4.0.5",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-logger": "^2.6.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.3.26",
    "babel-core": "^6.3.26",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "eslint": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^6.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-meteor": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^4.2.3",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^0.9.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "react-transform-catch-errors": "^1.0.0",
    "react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.1",
    "redbox-react": "^1.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.4.1"
  }
```

The `package` file in the `.meteor` directory is a follows:

```
less@2.7.5
tidee-fontello
tidee-asset-loader
tidee-fonts
tidee-css
accounts-password@1.3.0
accounts-base@1.2.11
raix:handlebar-helpers
meteorhacks:zones
random@1.0.10
osv:mongo-counter
reywood:publish-composite


zenniz:jquery-placeholder
tidee-jquery-resize
reactive-var@1.0.10
gwendall:template-animations
meteor-base@1.0.4
mobile-experience@1.0.4
mongo@1.1.12
session@1.1.6
tracker@1.1.0
logging@1.1.15
reload@1.1.10
ejson@1.0.12
spacebars@1.0.12
check@1.2.3
tap:i18n
react-meteor-data
meteorhacks:unblock
dburles:collection-helpers
standard-minifier-css@1.2.0
standard-minifier-js@1.2.0
tomwasd:history-polyfill
blaze-html-templates@1.0.4
es5-shim@4.6.14
practicalmeteor:mocha
ecmascript@0.5.8
react
tidee-data-tables
aldeed:collection2
fongandrew:find-and-modify
jagi:astronomy
jagi:astronomy-validators
mouse0270:bootstrap-notify
gwendall:tapi18n-react
shell-server
tidee-bootstrap-3.3.7
tidee-jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom
```

There is no indication of which package is causing these warnings to occur. Is there any way to find this out? Alternatively, is there a way to hide this warning from being sent to the browser console?

Comment: Can you show us the entire error message along with the `dependencies` section of your `package.json` file?

Comment: The above messge is the full error message. I now have added the dependencies to the original question above.

Comment: Can you also show the contents of your packages file in the `.meteor` directory?

Comment: I have added the contents of the packages file to the original question above.

Comment: Hi, I've got the same issu. Any improvement on it ?

Comment: Nope. Please tick-up the question.